# box2dweb issue in DestroyJoint function

Tags: javascript, box2d

my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/H8e9m/11/

as you can see when the ball reach the pendulum end and collide with it by a revolute joint, the problem occurred when trying to make the ball release the pendulum by pressing the space button.

```
      if (keydown.space) {
        var list = physics.world.GetJointList();
         if (list.GetBodyB().m_userData.details.name=="End")
              physics.world.DestroyJoint(list);
            }
```

can anyone tell me how can i fix this problem please

Comment: Is that the correct jsfiddle link? In that code there is only one mention of revoluteBall_joint, and that is the line you show above. Of course it will be undefined.

Comment: yes it is the correct jsfiddle ... why it is not working with u ? i check it and the jsfiddle is working ... can u please explain why it is undefined ... even though i declare the revoluteBall_joint as a global variable and it's definition is declared when the ball make contact with the rope (when u jump by pressing the up button) you can see it in action by going to this link `http://jsfiddle.net/H8e9m/9/show`

Comment: What do you mean by "working"? I see a ball just sitting there, and a chain of bodies hanging. It seems like none of your keyboard input events are being detected. I put a console.log just before the DestroyJoint call you have above, and the log never shows up.

Comment: did u check the last link i sent ? and i updated my jsfiddle to : http://jsfiddle.net/H8e9m/11/show please see the progress .. i was able to destroy the joint between the ball and the end of the rope but the last body of the chain is also released from the chain wish is a problem ...what i want to do basically is a Tarzan like example .. when the ball hang to the rope and the user hit space the ball release the rope

Comment: Yes, but the ball is still on the left, not connected to anything at all. ah, looks like you changed the question. This is getting kinda hard to follow :) Instead of checking the name of the bodyB of the joint, why not just keep a reference to the joint when you create it? Then you can just use that reference to destroy it.

Comment: what browser are u using ? can u please use firefox maybe the library of the `keydown` is not working for u ... and how can i keep a reference ? i am declaring the joint globally outside the update function ` var revoluteBall_joint = new b2RevoluteJointDef();` but it was giving me a javascript error saying bodyA is not defined :/ :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the joint when you create it like this:

```
var myJointDef = new b2RevoluteJointDef();
revoluteBall_jointDef.bodyA = ...
... etc
myJoint = world.CreateJoint(jointDef);
```

The 'myJoint' variable should be global, eg. you could declare it here:

```
var myJoint = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2
       ,b2AABB = Box2D.Collision.b2AABB
       ... etc
```

Then you should be able to destroy the joint from any point in your code later.